# Monitoring of jersey server

Tags: java, server, jersey, monitoring

I would like to monitor my jersey server, starting with counting the number of incoming request.

I am following the official guide from here: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/monitoring_tracing.html

I understand the concept of Application event listener and request event listener. However, I dont understand the concept of registering the application event listener. My question is where to put the following piece of code (in the MyApplicationEventListener or in a separate class):

```
ResourceConfig resourceConfig =
        new ResourceConfig(TestResource.class, MyApplicationEventListener.class)
        .setApplicationName("my-monitored-application");
```

The same question for this piece of code:

```
target.path("resource").request()
    .post(Entity.entity("post", MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_TYPE));
target.path("resource").request().get();
```

If you can show a complete Java project, it would be perfect for me and other people looking for the answer of this question.

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be used like this.

```
@Configuration
public class EndpointsConfig extends ResourceConfig {
  /**
   * Configures all necessary features, endpoints and properties.
  */
   public EndpointsConfig() throws UnknownHostException {
   // register features
      register(MyApplicationEventListener.class);
   }
}
```